# Array Index out of Bound in converting an array of pixels into a Image in Java

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have this method that I found on stackoverflow:

```
    public static Image getImageFromArray(int[] pixels, int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) image.getData();
        raster.setPixels(0,0,width,height,pixels);
        return image;
    }
```

using it like this:

```
        image = getImageFromArray(dstpixels,img.getWidth(this),img.getHeight(this));
```

In order to debug I printed out Width, Height and length of dstpixels, here are the results:
700 389
272300

still I get this error
 `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 272300`

on this exact line

```
            raster.setPixels(0,0,width,height,pixels);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Raster doesn't treat `pixels` as array in which each element represents single pixel. It treats it as array where each element contains single information about pixel.
So if it is ARGB type of image it looks like `pixel` array will contain info about first pixel in first four elements (at indexes `[0,1,2,3]`) where

- `R` will be stored at position `[0]`
- `G` at position `[1]`
- `B` at position `[2]`
- and `A` (alpha) at position `[3]`.

Info about second pixel will be placed at `[4,5,6,7]` indexes, third `[8,9,10,11]` and so on.

So main problem from your question can be solved by assigning 4 times larger `int[] pixel` array than amount of pixels for ARGB type of image (for RGB 3 times larger).

Another problem in your code is that `image.getData()`

> Returns the image as one large tile. The Raster returned is a ***copy of the image*** data is not updated if the image is changed.

(emphasis mine)

so manipulating data from that `raster` will not affect `image`. To update image with data from raster you need to add `image.setData(raster);` in your `getImageFromArray` method like

```
public static Image getImageFromArray(int[] pixels, int w, int h) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) image.getData();
    raster.setPixels(0,0,w,h,pixels);
    image.setData(raster); //<-- add this line
    return image;
}
```

OR don't use `image.getData()` at all and instead manipulate raster used by image. You can get it via `image.getRaster()`.

Demo:

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int width = 200, height = 300;
    //array needs to be 4 times larger than amount of pixels
    int[] pixels = new int[4*width*height];
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        //if (i%4==0){pixels[i]=255;}//R default 0
        //if (i%4==1){pixels[i]=255;}//G default 0
        if (i%4==2){pixels[i]=255;}//B default 0 
        //Alpha
        if (i%4==3){        
            pixels[i]=(int)(255*(i/4%width)/(double)width);
        }
    }
    Image image = getImageFromArray(pixels, width, height);
    showImage(image);
}
public static void showImage(Image img){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabel lab = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
    frame.add(lab);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public static Image getImageFromArray(int[] pixels, int w, int h) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    raster.setPixels(0,0,w,h,pixels);
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In order to debug I printed out Width, Height and length of dstpixels, here are the results: 700 389 **272300**

And

> still I get this error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: **272300**

If the array size is N, then the index of the first element is 0 and the index of the last element is N-1 (in your case 0 and 272299)

Comment: I tried making the array with 1 less element and still get the same error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 272299

Answer (score 0):

Seems that one of your parameters should be 272300-1!

The exception is telling you that something accesses index 272300, which won't work if that is the SIZE of the dimension; then the last index is as said, 272300-1.

In other words: always read the exception message carefully, it tells you all you need to know!

Comment: I tried making the array with 1 less element and still get the same error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 272299

Comment: Don't shrink the array, change the parameters to the calls you are making!